# display message on LogOn page when session time out in asp.net mvc3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, session, c#-4.0, authorization

i want to display session time out message on my LogOn page.

i have override asp.net mvc Authorize attribute to naviagate the user to logOn page on session timeOut but my problem is that i am not able to set ViewData or ViewBag or Session["Message"]
kind of thing inside that override method.

i would request you all to please help me ...

how to set ViewData inside that Override method.

below is my CustomAuthorizeAttribute class

```
public class CustomAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
    {

        public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
        {
            if (filterContext == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("filterContext");
            }

            if (!filterContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated || SessionCache.User_ID == 0)
            {
                // User not logged in, redirect to login page 
                filterContext.Result = new HttpUnauthorizedResult();
                return;
            }

        }

    }
```

please suggest.

thanks,

Comment: post your Authorize attribute code

Comment: what happens currently when the session times out?

Comment: Mark will post my Authorize attribute code this coming monday....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to look into using Session_End event in your Global.asax.

It's important to realize that Session_End will only be called on InProc sessions.